# What does a: classname mean as a parameter in function on discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been using discord.py for some time.I got stuck with this problem.I couldn't understand **member:discord.Member** statement.How does that help us in that module or in general?If I want to run this funct,which type of argument I should pass for **member: discord.Member** ?

```
async def mute(self,ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
```

Ps:**discord** is a name of the module and **Member** is a class in this module

Comment: It's a [type hint.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) It's basically telling the user, "hey the parameter `member` needs to be of this type". Python doesn't enforce type hints; they're purely for documentation. There are some modules that can perform type-checking and enforcement.

Comment: You need to obtain some instance of `discord.Member` class, and pass it. In the current example this passed member will be muted.